# HTML5 Drag & Drop File Upload gets JavaScript 'permission denied' accessing FileInfo object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upload a single file using standard multipart upload. It should work just as if there was a form on the page with a file field and a text field and a submit button at the bottom. They identify the file, type in a few other strings and click the "upload" button. In this case, though the form is just a dummy used to create a FileForm object. And the text field and file field and drop box are just random DOM elements with JS behind them. (HTML and jQuery/JavaScript below.)

So, concerning the non-form code, it works (meaning the file uploads and I can see the bytes on the server) **only if** the user uses the `<input type="file" .../>` element to identify the file.

If the user does a drag and drop of a file onto a spot on the page, I save the file info in a data element and use it from there instead of from the file input field. But when a file is dropped, an error (shown below) occurs because the code isn't allowed to get a single file out of the FileList returned by the drop.

So I put all the relevant code here and set up a fiddle. But, when I strip it down to the jsFiddle (linked below), both methods work.

That truly messes up the whole question. But I'm going to submit it anyway because it has code pulled together and simplified from a lot of older SO questions for doing file uploads and drag & drop. Plus someone might know what could cause the error.

**Question:** What sorts of things should I look for on my full page that would cause the contents of the dropped FileInfo object to become protected? That's the question for now.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2RQhc/7/)

Here's the error message:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'length'
    if (files.length > 1) {
```

Here's the HTML

```
<label for="dropbox">
    <span>DROP HERE:</span>
    <!-- CSS makes this a big purple bordered box -->
    <div id="dropbox">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="dropfile"></div>
</label>
<label for="inputFile">
    <span>FILES:</span>
    <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile"/>
</label>

<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload"/>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="fileform"></form>
```

Here's the JS w/ jQuery

```
$.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
$("#dropbox").on("drop", function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();

     var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
     var files = dt.files;
     // errors on these lines *******************************************
     if (files.length > 1) { alert(files.length + " files dropped. Only 1 allowed"); }
     var file = files[0];
     // errors on these lines *******************************************

     $("#dropfile").text(file.name);
     $("#dropbox").data("file", file);
     try {
         $("#inputFile").val(""); // works in some browsers
     } catch (e) {
         // ignore failure in some browsers
     }
});

$("#dropbox").on("dragenter", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#dropbox").on("dragover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#inputFile").change(function(e) { // selecting a file, erases dropped one
    $("#dropfile").text("");
    $("#dropbox").removeData("file");
});

$("#upload").click(function() {
    var data = new FormData($("#fileform")[0]);
    var obj = readTextBoxes();
    for (var prop in obj) {
        data.append(prop, obj[prop]);
    }

    // HTML file input user's choice(s)...
    var dropfile = $("#dropbox").data("file");
    if (dropfile) {
        data.append("inputFile", dropfile);
    } else {
        $.each($("#inputFile")[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append("inputFile[" + i + "]", file);
        });
    }

    var parms = {
        url : baseUrl + "v2/document/upload",
        type : "POST",
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType     
        data : data,  
        timeout : 40000
    };
    var promise = $.ajax(parms);
    // ... handle response
});
```

Comment: Can you double check that your doctype is set to <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @KerryLiu Nope. It wasn't. Changing to see what happens.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Seeing the same in Firefox but works fine in Chrome.